# Jquery Moving only unavailable options from one select to another

Tags: jquery

I am using the below to move my selected options from select 1 to select 2.

```
selectedOps= $("#select1 option:selected");


$("#select2").append($(selectedOpts).clone());
```

I  want to append only the options that are not moved already. I am not sure how to add that check in the above statement. How to move only those options which are not already moved?

Comment: Can you just empty the second select before appending? That is certainly simplest.  However creating a filter is not difficult either if that is not a viable solution for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a method to serialise the `<option>` elements into a value object (like a string for example) that you can use in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in order to filter out duplicates.

Then...

1. Grab the options from `#select2` and the selected options from `#select1`
2. Serialise them all and put them in a `Set`
3. Pull them back out of the `Set` and deserialise them back into options in `#select2`

This has the advantage of maintaining the original order of insertion for when you add options to `#select2`.

```js
const serialiser = (_, { value, textContent }) => `${value}:${textContent}`
const deserialiser = hash => {
  const [ value, text ] = hash.split(":")
  return $("<option>", { value, text })
}

const sel1 = $("#select1")
const sel2 = $("#select2")

$("#copy").on("click", () => {
  const options = sel2.find("option")
    .map(serialiser).get()
  const selected = sel1.find("option:selected")
    .map(serialiser).get()
    
  const merged = new Set([...options, ...selected])
  sel2.empty().append(Array.from(merged, deserialiser))
})
```

```css
div { display: flex; align-items: center; }
select { flex-grow: 1; margin: 0 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="select1" size="5" multiple>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button" id="copy">▶</button>

  <select id="select2" size="5" readonly></select>
</div>
```